# How to parse string into an array of objects?

Tags: python, arrays, json

I have a python app that send a strange array of objects to my node js app in string format like this :

`"[{'foo':'bar'},{'hello':'world'}]"`

I am trying to parse it with `JSON.parse()` but I get errors :

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1`

On python side the array is recognized as a true array list but when I pass it to nodejs with python shell , this become a stringified array of objects.

Any suggestion to parse it ?

Comment: Fix your Python app so that it sends proper JSON instead

Comment: I think there is nothing wrong with my python app I am using the native json module with `json.loads` and `json.dumps` to before sending my json

Comment: The string you posted is not valid JSON. It would help to see the Python code that generated this response and fix any issues there.

Answer (score 0):

JSON.parse() will not accept single quotes as string boundaries. This string, using double quotes, works fine:

```js
console.log(JSON.parse('[{"foo":"bar"},{"hello":"world"}]'));
```

If it is impossible to change the Python app, you may replace the single quotes to double quotes before JSON parsing the string.

Answer (score 0):

How about using json.load()?

```
import json
inp = "[{'foo':'bar'},{'hello':'world'}]"

a = json.loads(inp.replace("'",'"'))

print(a)
```

Output (list of dictionaries) :

```
[{'foo': 'bar'}, {'hello': 'world'}]
```